# boost::asio - async_read_some and boost::asio::socket_base::bytes_readable

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, tcp, asio

I have a problem with the function `async_read_some()`. I am running cyclicly the function `receiveAsyncWithTimeout()` by a timer.

**Expected working**
The function `receiveAsyncWithTimeout()` should read all messages from my server.

**Problems**

1. **bytesTransferred** and  **bytesReadable** are different.
2. Messages are received weirdly. First one frame, after about 10 seconds the rest.

**Boost version:** 1.77

output:

```
readHandle bytesReadable: 0 bytesTransferred: 1112
```

**pseudocode:**

```cpp
class TlsSocket 
{
public:
    TlsSocket(boost::asio::io_context &io_context,
              const std::string &endpoint);
private:
    boost::asio::io_context &_iocontext;
    boost::asio::ssl::context _ctx;
    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> _socket;
    std::vector<uint8_t> _recvBuffer;
    std::vector<uint8_t> _sendBuffer;
    size_t _bytesReadable{0};
}

void TlsSocket::readHandle(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytesTransferred)
{
    if(_bytesReadable == 0 && bytesTransferred > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "readHandle ERROR bytesReadable: " << _bytesReadable
                  << " bytesTransferred: " << bytesTransferred << std::endl;
        return;
    }

/// .. any code
}

void TlsSocket::receiveAsyncWithTimeout()
{
    boost::asio::socket_base::bytes_readable command(true);
    _socket.lowest_layer().io_control(command);
    _bytesReadable = command.get();
    
     _socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(_recvBuffer),
                            boost::bind(&TlsSocket::readHandle,
                                        this,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

Comment: In general, framing and delivery can not be relied on. TCP stacks are free to re-arrange for optimal resource utilization (both kernel, on the wire etc). There are a number of options that can tune this (TCP_NODELAY, QUICKACK e.g.) as well as sysctls and sometimes your physical adaptor(s). SSL adds a layer of indirection on top of all that. If you have trouble you can always give a self-contained, working example and we can reproduce the issue/suggest remedies. However, none of us can run pseudo-code (not even you) so for now you'll have to do with general comments like this.